# Domino tiling extended in N dimensions.

Tags: permutations, fibonacci-numbers

The standard domino tiling problem, is the number of ways to tile a board of size 2xn by dominos of size 2x1. The answer directly follows a recursion, the same as the Fibonacci series.

If I extend this to M dimensions:
Board of size (2x2x2...x2)xn has to be tiled by dominos of size 2x1x1...x1, I was wondering if we can define a way to calculate the number of ways, given a value of M, and developing the recursive function for that value of M. Then getting a series. In particular I wanted help with an approach to extend this to bigger dimensions.

Particular case:

Boardsize 2 × 2 × 2 × 2 × n. Divide into 8n parts of 1 × 1 × 1 × 1 × 2 each. The direction doesn't matter, 1 × 1 × 1 × 2 × 1 and 2 × 1 × 1 × 1 × 1 are both fine and 2 different ways

Thank you

Comment: Nice idea! It will be somewhat difficult to denote the positions of the dominos in $4$ or more dimensions.

Comment: You won't get nearly as simple a recurrence, because in the 2D recurrence really just depends on the orientation of one domino.

Comment: I know. I guess a start would be to calculate it for 3 and then see if there is a relation between n=2 and n=3. Then draw parallels, use similar approaches and extend to n=4,5.

Comment: Yeah, I get that the recurrence won't be simple, but there has to be some relation, which is what I'm trying to figure out and asking help for.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "has to be a relation." There might well be no remotely reasonable recurrence at all.

Comment: Well, if I was to simply ask the question to solve the above case for 2x2xn and tile this using 1x1x2 dominos( or 2x1x1/1x2x1), what would be the way to do this, for n? Clearly a series will be generated, which most likely should have a relation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I suspect it can still be shown that the answer is found as a single component of an appropriate linear recurrence relation, though.

Comment: Pulling @achille_hui's comment from the first answer: potential answerers should be aware that this is apparently a contest problem on codechef right now, though I can't find any rules on their site about outside assistance.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: it turns out there is a simple value in 3D.  I was surprised to see that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be from [an ongoing context](https://www.codechef.com/JAN16/problems/DMCS) which will last the whole month of January.

Answer (score 0):

Using a computer, if the number of dimensions is small (e.g. like $3$ or $4$), a straightforward way to get a recurrence that can be solved for a formula is to let $a_{n,S}$ be the number of ways to finish a tiling when there are $n$ $2 \times 2 \times \ldots \times 2$ "slabs" to fill and the first slab has subset $S$ already filled (and all other slabs are empty). Then your desired quantity is $a_{n,\emptyset}$. You can express each of the $a_{n,S'}$ (for each $S'$) as some linear combination of all the $a_{n-1,S}$. The linear combination can be computed by brute force, considering all ways to finish filling in the first slab (that has subset $S'$ already filled) where it is allowed to place dominos that are oriented to fill one space in the current slab and one space in the next slab, creating some filled subset $S$ in the next slab. This gives a system of what's called linear difference equations, with potentially many many variables (because the number of possible $S$ grows super-exponentially as the number of dimensions in your slabs increases), but such a system can be solved with linear algebra (you can read about solving linear difference equations online), giving closed form formulas in terms of $n$ and the initial values $a_{1,S}$ which can be computed with brute force enumeration.

Comment: Boardsize 2 × 2 × 2 × 2 × n.
Divide into 8n parts of 1 × 1 × 1 × 1 × 2 each. The direction doesn't matter, 1 × 1 × 1 × 2 × 1 and 2 × 1 × 1 × 1 × 1 are both fine and 2 different ways.

Comment: You only need one variable for each configuration above a slab, though with dominoes you need to consider two layers above a filled slab.

Answer (score 0):

For three dimensions, you can find a set of coupled recurrences.  The trick is to make sure you count each configuration once.  Imagine you are building a $2 \times 2 \times n$ brick with the $n$ direction vertical.  Number the available positions $1$ to $4$.  Require that each domino added fill the lowest number position in the lowest available layer.  You can define a set of coupled recurrences for the number of ways to have $n$ full layers plus each possible configuration above the full layers.  For example $a(n)$ is the number of ways to exactly fill $n$ layers.  $b(n)$ is the number of ways to fill $n$ full layers plus positions $1$ and $2$ in the next layer.  $c(n)$ is the number of ways to fill $n$ full layers plus two high in position $1$.  I find twelve different possible configurations, so you will have twelve coupled recurrences.  According to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006253), it is the closest integer to  $(2+\sqrt 3)^n/6$  It will get much more complicated in more dimensions.

Here are my recurrences.  The first column is the letter for the configuration.  The next picture shows the height of that configuration above the last filled layer.  The last column shows the recurrences between them.  I numbered the cells starting with the upper left and going clockwise, so in configuration A you have to fill the upper left.  There are three ways to do that, which take you to B, C, and H without filling a layer, so each of those has a term $A(n)$ in the recurrence.  Similarly, if you are in B you can put a block lying down and get to A with one more full layer or put a block vertical and get to D, so D has a term $B(n)$ and A has a term $B(n-1)$.

[image]

Comment: $A(9) = 87362$, ref: [OEIS A006253](http://oeis.org/A006253). BTW, please don't talk about the $5D$ case until 11-th (it is part of an ongoing contest on codechef).

Comment: @achillehui:  found it.  Thanks for the reference.  I won't do 5D, or even 4D, at all